# Android Firebase code in custom function return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

this function return message it return null i need solution to return value thanks

```
public String saveData(final User user) {
        final String[] message = new String[1];
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail().toString(), user.getPassword().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                message[0] = "Fail" + e.getMessage();
            }
        });

        return message[0];
    }
```

Comment: You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is asynchronous operation - so `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` callbacks will be triggered lately in the future. But you will return `message[0]` immediately after starting operation - that's why you get `null` result.
To solve that problem you can pass callbacks as arguments to your function and handle result when that callbacks will be triggered. For example,

```
public void saveData(final User user, OnSuccessListener<AuthResult> success, OnFailureListener failure) {
    final String[] message = new String[1];
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail().toString(), user.getPassword().toString())
            .addOnSuccessListener(success).addOnFailureListener(failure);
}
```

and invoke it

```
saveData(user, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    // TODO handle result
                }
            }, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            String message = "Fail" + e.getMessage();
        }
    });
```

Something like that.

Comment: this solution is very good but, when i used to  this solution with MVP Pattern , i send two object (OnSuccessListener<AuthResult> success, OnFailureListener failure) in presenter constructor that make view careless.can you send example of user firebase with MVP Pattern thanks

Comment: @user9213317 if we speak about MVP and you want that code to be placed in `Presenter`, you shouldn't pass that callbacks in constructor - simply you can trigger `View` directly inside that callbakcs (implemented by `presenter`)